# Line break, echo in input/textarea

Tags: wordpress

Trying to add text from url, so if isset url exist in current url path it will show  specific text inside textarea.

```
<textarea>
<?php if(isset($_GET['url'])) {
echo 'Text 1';
echo "\n";
echo 'Text 2';
} ?>
</textarea>
```

But in textarea I get `<br />` showed.

```
Text 1.<br />
Text 2.
```

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code. Tried and it works, it shows a textarea with two lines

Comment: It's wpautop what cause problem in WordPress. Was simple, but wasn't on my mind that could be a reason.